# how do i do utf8 encoding for AFHTTPClient?

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption

i have tried the following code

```
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/"]];

[client setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];

[client postPath:@"hello123" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"v1", @"k1", @"v2", @"k2", nil]
         success:^(id object) {
             NSLog(@"%@", object);
         } failure:^(NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"%@", error);
         }];
[client release];
```

in the above code 
      **[client setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];**
will this line do utf encoding ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Also see https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ

Answer (score 0):

`AFJSONParameterEncoding` isn't a string encoding. so it doesn't make it utf8.

It says to make all the parameters you pass and write them to the http-body as one big JSON object.

---

It doesn't affect string encoding at all.

**In fact I dont think anything in AFNetworking touches the string encoding** => so it purely what you pass in OR (in case of json) what the apple framework JSON serializer generates